# Coordinate Restrictions

Tags: javascript, d3.js, coordinates, draggable

so, here I am with another of my questions:
I have a network set up in D3. Its nodes are all unfixed but one. All unfixed can be dragged wherever you want, but within the svg. To provide this I test the new coordinates at the end of the script. But if I move the fixed node all the other are dragged together with this one.
My problem is, that the nodes seem to get their coordinates relative to the parent object, which, in this case, is a g-Elements that provides the group-dragging. So after dragging they still have the restrictions, but they are shifted together with the group. Any useful hints welcome :)
And here are parts of my code:

```
var node = group.selectAll(".node")
    .data(reqNodes)                                             
 .enter().append("g")                                   
    .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(0,0)"; })
    .attr("class", function(d) {
       return d.fixed ? 'node fixed' : 'node not-fixed';
     })

var CurrentGTransformX = 0;
var CurrentGTransformY = 0;

group.selectAll('.not-fixed')
  .call(force.drag);

  // attach a different drag handler to the fixed node
var groupDrag = d3.behavior.drag()
  .on("drag", function(d) {
    // mouse pos offset by starting node pos
    var x = window.event.clientX - 420,
    y = window.event.clientY - 260;
    group.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x + "," + y + ")"; });    
              //that was the line getting in conflict with the part in the end
    CurrentGTransformX = x;
    CurrentGTransformY = y;
  });

group.call(groupDrag);

force.on("tick", function() {
   node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x = Math.max(15, Math.min(width - 15, d.x)); })
       .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y = Math.max(15, Math.min(height - 15, d.y)); });

  link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
      .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
      .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
      .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

  node.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });
});
```

edit: the transformation of the group is the reason why the restrictions in the end get other data than displayed. Any idea how to serve both functions in the proper way?

Comment: I discovered that I can switch the focus to any other node I like, as long as I don't drag the fixed node. So I suppose the error is somewhere in the groupDrag-thing, well hidden. Suggestions?

Comment: what I need is a) a possibility to shift the elements without using a translate-attribute, or b) a way to take away the translation when I do the force.on-part. Does anyone have a suggestion?